# can't parse webhook signing secret from stripe cli

Tags: stripe-payments

when I start stripe CLI it generates endpoint secret with arrow symbol "←[1mwhsec_zGikAg19N5FOHXai7uOuzD8HHErIByOw←[0m" and couldn't process this in java so getting com.stripe.exception.SignatureVerificationException: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. can someone suggest how to parse this secret?

Sample- 
D:\project\course\stripe\stripe_1.2.9_windows_x86_64>stripe listen --forward-to localhost:4343/webhoo

> Ready! Your webhook signing secret is ←[1mwhsec_zGikAg19N5FOHXai7uOuzD8HHErIByOw←[0m (^C to quit)

Comment: could you share your exact Java code that handles the webhook event?

Comment: i am using official stripe sample from webhook from https://github.com/stripe-samples/charging-for-multiple-plan-subscriptions/blob/master/server/java/src/main/java/com/stripe/sample/Server.java ,

Comment: Hmm. Well bear in mind the actual secret looks like `whsec_xxx` So those bits with `←` sound like something your terminal or shell is adding(it probably doesn't support the formatting stripe-cli is trying to use) so you should just make sure that you edit and only use the `whsec_xxx` part inside the app, like 'whsec_zGikAg19N5FOHXai7uOuzD8HHErIByOw'

Comment: thank you so much. that is how I fixed. stripe cli generating token was confused